# 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.21.1

Tags: laravel, nginx, vagrant, homestead, bad-gateway

## Initial situation

Have a Laravel App on a Vagrant Box, Ubuntu 20.04 and Nginx, installed with **Homestead**.
I use browsersync to watch for file changes.

## Issue

Suddenly I get a 502 Bad Gateway error at the URL localhost:3000, when `npm run watch` is running.

However if i do `php artisan serve`, the provided local url 127.0.0.1:8000 and the myproject.test domain are working correct if i open one of the url's in a browser.
But browsersync don't update this url's, it syncs only over localhost:3000.

## Allready tried

- `vagrant destroy` & `vagrant up`

## Question

What can i do, to find out why i'm getting this error at localhost:3000 and at 127.0.0.1:8000 not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use port forwarding to force data from VM ip to localhost but it's easier to just use virtual machine's ip.**

#### To take an IP of you virtual machine you can do this by one of these guides:

- Open a terminal, cd to the path of your Vagrantfile and write this

(Linux)

vagrant ssh -c "hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f2" 2>/dev/null

(OS X)

vagrant ssh -c "hostname -I | cut -d' ' -f2" 2>/dev/null | pbcopy

The command for Linux also works for windows. I have no way to test, sorry. source:

https://coderwall.com/p/etzdmq/get-vagrant-box-guest-ip-from-host

#### After this, put an ip with ports which were specified for nginx in your browser.

Comment: Asewsome! I just replaced myproject.test with the ip from clipboard in my webpack file like `mix.browserSync({proxy: 'http://192.168.10.10/'});`. Thank you so much!